# How to show data with the async command in the template?

Tags: javascript, angular, react-redux, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular 8 application. And I am using the `async`command for passing data from child to parent component. But the data is returning by the server but is not been displayed by the `HTML` template.

This is my `typescript`:

```
correspondenceEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry[]>;
  attachmentEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry[]>;

  @Input() allCorrespondence: Array<DossierEntry>;
  @Input() correspondenceEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;
  @Input() attachmentEntries: Array<DossierEntry>;

  message = '';
  emptyMessageCorrespondentie = 'Geen correspondentie.';
  errorMessageConnection = 'Er ging iets mis met de connectie. Probeer over enkele minuten nogmaals.';

  correspondenceLoaded = false;

  showingSingle = false;

  single: DossierEntry;

  constructor(private documentCorrespondeceService: DocumentCorrespondenceService, private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {


    this.authService.loginStatus().subscribe(user => {
      const UUID = user.profile.participant;

      this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry(UUID, 'correspondence').subscribe(result => {
        this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      }, msg => (this.message = this.emptyMessageCorrespondentie));
    });
  }

  handleCorrespondenceLoad(result: any) {
    if (result.length === 0) {
      this.message = this.emptyMessageCorrespondentie;
      return;
    }
    this.allCorrespondence = result;
    this.attachmentEntries = [];
    this.correspondenceEntries = [];

    const groups = _.groupBy(result, 'type');
    console.log(this.correspondenceEntries = groups.correspondence);
    console.log(this.attachmentEntries = groups.attachments);
    this.correspondenceEntries = groups.correspondence;
    this.attachmentEntries = groups.attachments;
  }
```

And here is the `HTML` template:

```
<h2 class="dossier-page-header">Correspondentie</h2>

  <p class="data-entry" *ngIf="!allCorrespondence">{{ message }}</p>


<ng-container *ngIf="(correspondenceEntries$ | async) as correspondenceEntries">
  <app-dossier-correspondence-list [correspondenceEntries]="correspondenceEntries" ></app-dossier-correspondence-list>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="(attachmentEntries$ | async) as attachmentEntries">
  <app-dossier-correspondence-attachments [attachmentEntries] = "attachmentEntries"></app-dossier-correspondence-attachments>
</ng-container>


  <app-dossier-correspondence-item
    [item]="single"
    (goBack)="goBack($event)"
    *ngIf="showingSingle">
  </app-dossier-correspondence-item>
```

So when I do this:

```
console.log(this.correspondenceEntries = groups.correspondence);
    console.log(this.attachmentEntries = groups.attachments);
```

I see the data:

```
Array(13)
:4200/dossier-dossier-module-ngfactory.js:17533 Array(3)
```

But it's not displayed in the view.

So how to improve this, that the data will also be showing in the view.

Thank you.

I understand.

But How to do this then:

```
this.attachmentEntries$ =     this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry(UUID, 'correspondence').subscribe(result => {
        this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      }, msg => (this.message = this.emptyMessageCorrespondentie));
    });
```

Of course this doenst work.So how to use the Observables:

```
correspondenceEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry[]>;
  attachmentEntries$: Observable<DossierEntry[]>;
```

?

Because there are two arrays.

So you mean like this:

```
<app-dossier-correspondence-list *ngFor="let item of correspondenceEntries"  ></app-dossier-correspondence-list>
```

and this:

```
ngOnInit() {


    this.authService.loginStatus().subscribe(user => {
      const UUID = user.profile.participant;

      this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry(UUID, 'correspondence').subscribe(result => {
        this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      }, msg => (this.message = this.emptyMessageCorrespondentie));
    });
  }
```

But the

child component looks already like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!showingSingle  && correspondenceEntries && correspondenceEntries.length > 0;">
  <div class="main-row main-row-dossier">
    <section class="data-entry">
      <h3 class="dossier-header">Algemeen</h3>
      <table class="dossier-table" *ngIf="correspondenceEntries  else loadingCorrespondenceEntires ">
        <thead class="dossier-tableheader">
          <tr>
            <th class="dossier-tablehead fixed-one-fifth">Datum</th>
            <th class="dossier-tablehead fixed-four-fifths">Onderwerp</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="dossier-tablebody">
          <tr class="dossier-correspondencerow" *ngFor="let entry of correspondenceEntries; let i = index" (click)="gotoItem(i, entry.type)">
            <td>{{ entry.date | date:"dd-MM-y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #loadingCorrespondenceEntires>
  <div>..Loading </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing 2 ways to subscribe to an Observable. Choose one, don't do both.

Solution 1:

```
// component
this.myService.getDataFromServer().subscribe(
  result => this.data = result
);

<!-- HTML -->
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  <span>{{item.label}}</span>
</div>
```

Solution 2:

```
// component
this.data$ = this.myService.getDataFromServer()

<!-- HTML -->
<div *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data">
  <span>{{data.label}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Yes, I understand that. But how to combine that in the this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry what I have now. I edit the post

Comment: I edit the post with let. But I dont see the data in the view

Comment: You cannot do `this.myData$ = this.myService().subscribe(...)` You have to choose: Use `this.myData$` or use `subscribe` and then never use the `| async`

Comment: On the code you wrote, you should delete the variable `attachmentEntries$`, and directly use `<ng-container *ngIf="correspondenceEntries">`

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you've been confused by my `*ngFor`, which was an exemple. The `let` syntax is for an `*ngFor`, this is not the point. The point is about using `| async` and a variable ending with a `$` symbol.

Comment: yes, oke, my mistake. But is there a performance issue. I mean if you do it with async or without?

Comment: nope, the only difference is that `| async` does unsubscribe on component death, so it is better when you use a custom `Sujbect`. But here, you are using an Observable (from an HTTP call), so no difference.